# Difference in `width` and `height` default settings

Tags: css, height, width, default, default-value

For the default settings in my browser, `width` gets the default value `100%` and `height` get the default value `auto`.

As known, the default effects vertically and horisontally are very different. The width of the box (a `<div>` e.g., but the element used will of course change the result) will then be 100% of the surrounding container block element as default. And the height will apparently equal the text height.

But if I set `width: auto;`, meaning that both `width` and `height` now have the same value `auto`, then the effects are still very different (and in fact there is no difference for the width).

(I use newest version of Google Chrome on Windows 7, but that doesn't make any big difference - the browsers aren't that different here.)

My question here is, how come there is such a difference in these two very alike proporties `width` and `height`? Such a big difference that the value `auto` gives a very different result from the two?

It is quite exhausting to obtain the same effects as the default effects from one on the other element. That is, it is quite hard and needs extra work / workarounds to obtain the effect of a 100% height as well as the effect of a width that fits to the text width. What I'm looking for is to understand these two proporties and their `auto` value better. I'f you guys have some good sources and links, I would be glad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is confusing, but I will answer from what I've understood

`div` is a block level element with a default `height` of `auto` and a default `width` of `100%` so if you expect that the height = text height, than the width = sentence/paragraph width than you need to use `display: inline-block;` or `float`

So in short, `height` is `auto` by default and `width` is `100%` for a block level element.

For an inline element, `height` is auto and `width` is auto (`height`, `width` won't effect unless you use `display: inline-block;`)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fEKDD/)

Comment: Thanks, I wrote something wrong at firsthand. I have updated the question. The question regards the results from setting `auto` on both the `width` and the `height`. There is still a remarkable difference in the results.

Comment: I get it, thanks. I am just wondering why the `auto` value fx is so different from the two. I need to do extra work on `width` to make it fit to the text width, in the same way that the height fits to the text height.

Comment: @Steeven yea, you welcome, take a look at block, inline elements :)

Comment: I know, I know :) It's not _how_ to work around it, it's more a question of _why_ there is such a difference. That is what bothers me.

Comment: @Steeven it's a construct, in order to differ the block and inline, the width of the blocks take up 100% unless floated or the display is changed using css

Comment: Okay, thanks. You don't have a link somewhere for the documentation about this, have you?

Comment: @Mr.Alien - You seem to be confusing the concept of shrink-wrapping with auto width. They are not the same. Neither is auto width of blocks the same as 100% width of blocks. See http://jsfiddle.net/fEKDD/1/ and how the first div is wider that the second.

Comment: @Alohci that's what I told him, that blocks are 100% by default..kinda not 100% width but 100% of the viewport, sorry if it sounds misguiding

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, the way that `auto` is evaluated for heights and widths in traditional CSS is very different from each other, which falls out as a consequence of the way that the [Normal Flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow) works.

The way widths and heights are converted from values like `auto` into used values is described in full detail in [section 10 of the CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html).